# ag-grid Angular 1 onFilterModified event how to get params

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ag-grid

I am adding grid options like below code :

```
var gridOptions = {
columnDefs: columnDefs,
rowData: null,
enableFilter: true,
onFilterChanged: function() {console.log('onFilterChanged');},
onFilterModified: function() {console.log('onFilterModified');}
};
```

But in **event onFilterModified** - I am not able to get params or filter details.

Please suggest if someone has any idea.

Answer (score 0):

you can get filter model by calling 
    `$scope.gridOptions.api.getFilterModel()` so if you want to get filter model after any change you can call method inside onFilterModified callback
    `$scope.gridOptions = {
         ... 
         onFilterModified: function(event){
         console.log($scope.gridOptions.api.getFilterModel())
         }
    }`

Comment: yes, it takes event as param but nothing comes into this param.

Comment: you are right, then i would suggest what @S.Baggy already told:
    `console.log($scope.gridOptions.api.getFilterModel());`

inside onFilterModified callback

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I do it.

```
function onFilterChange() {
    console.log($scope.gridOptions.api.getFilterModel());
}
```

And in the gridOptions setup...

```
onAfterFilterChanged: function () { onFilterChange(); },
```